# Utilizar "ToUInt64()" para formatar string é correto?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Procurando por uma maneria prática de formatar `string` me deparei com o seguinte: `Convert.ToUInt64(string).ToString(@"00000\-000")`.

É uma boa pática utilizar este método para formatar `strings`? Existe uma forma recomendada?

Segue um exemplo da utilização:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var nomeCep = "JOSE - 09017092";
        var cep = nomeCep.Split('-')[1];
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt64(cep).ToString(@"00000\-000"));
    }
}
```

> Resultado: 09017-092

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se atinge o resultado esperado em todas situações não posso dizer que é errado. Mas considero gambiarra (que às vezes é a melhor forma).

Mas eu não faria isso. Texto é texto, número é número. O fato de um texto conter apenas dígitos numéricos não faz dele um número. CEP não é usado para cálculos. Eu sempre evitaria tratá-los como se fossem números em qualquer circunstância. Então eu não usaria essa conversão e formataria como texto mesmo:

```
var nomeCep = "JOSE - 09017092";
var cep = nomeCep.Split('-')[1];
WriteLine($"{cep.Substring(0, 6)}-{cep.Substring(6, 3)}");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ohrfdD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tFRsCd). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatCep.cs).

Obviamente tem diversas outras formas.

Eu até acho que o .NET precisa de uma biblioteca um pouco melhor para formatar texto, capricharam só em números e datas. Se eu achar alguma biblioteca externa eu posto aqui, mas não lembro de ter visto nada. Só [achei um método de extensão](http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/string/formatwithmask) simples, mas que dá conta de vários cenários.